# Multiple content areas per page

Tags: customization, shortcode, content

I’m having a complex content issue. Each page can have multiple sections (unknown number), each section can have multiple containers, each container can have multiple content blocks (either 1, 2 or 3).

I’ve currently got a theoretical solution with shortcodes, but I would like to solve this with the UI if possible by providing wysiwyg editors for each content block.

Sections: There can be any number of sections (a realistic/acceptable maximum would be 10).
Containers: A section can contain any number of rows (a realistic/acceptable maximum would be 5).
Containers: A row must know how many columns it needs to contain.
Content blocks: A row can contain 1, 2 or 3 columns.

The shortcode solution looks something like this:

```
[section id="summary"] //id is required but can be anything (no spaces)
   [container blocks="1"] //row can have 1, 2 or 3 columns
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
   [/container]
[/section]
[section id="find us"] //id is required but can be anything (no spaces)
   [container blocks="3"] //row can have 1, 2 or 3 columns
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
   [/container]
[/section]
[section id="team"] //id is required but can be anything (no spaces)
   [container blocks="2"] //row can have 1, 2 or 3 columns
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
      [block]
      .content-block
      [/block]
   [/container]
[/section]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about this?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: sounds like you are recreating html tables. you can with some plugins just add table editing capability to the editor

Comment: @MarkKaplun It sounds like that because I've used the terms 'row' and 'column', but they are not tables. This will be used for layout, not data, so I won't be using tables, I will be using sections, articles and divs. Besides there will be HTML in between each section and row that will come from the template.

Comment: in html table is a type of layout. if you are talking about columns then you are talking about tables with one row or more. If you want each section is a table. I really don't see the need to reinvent something that is in the html standard

Comment: Try searching around for how you can add styles to the tiny mce editor within WordPress. If you can trust your content editors to use these, you'll find the coding easier than for multiple content blocks.

Comment: @MarkKaplun it's seriously not. Google why you shouldn't use tables for layouts in HTML. I haven't had this debate in several years so I don't know of any recent articles about it, but the topic is well discussed.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Thanks, I'm  not entirely sure what you mean, but it has made me realise I could probably add buttons to the WYSIWYG to insert the shortcodes which would make it more user-friendly.

Comment: people that think that tables should not be used should not be in web design. seriously each tool needs to be used when appropriate, or do you think that the CSS wordking group have spec how to style divs as table with css because they were bored? You are trying to abuse the shortcode system. It was never intended to replace html elements. If you want a div, then let the author enter a div and add class to it as @AndyMacaulay-Brook says

Comment: I'm on my phone so tricky to give lots of detail. You can add, for example, "Find Us Block" to the style dropdown in the visual editor. Your users could highlight the content, choose this style and tiny mce would clad the selection in a div with the right ID.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook thank you, I see what you mean. That could also be an option. I will look into/think about it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun you are entitled to your opinion. However, I believe you are wrong, and I believe W3C who develop web standards have made it quite clear that tables are designed to be used to organise data, and not for layout design. But this is not the place for that discussion.

Comment: @MarkKaplun You should read the specification from W3C. Here's a quick quote. "Tables should not be used as layout aids." - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data

Comment: you are doing a table, it is not an layout aid in your case..... anyway religious people have all kinds of principals, but in the real world while it might be better to have a `display:table`CSS rule on the div to achieve the same, but the editor do not support inline CSS, but do support actual tables. In the end you need to decide what is more important to you, your religious beliefs on what html elements should not be used, or giving your editors the most useful tools to do their work. Nested shortcodes are horrible tor the user and easy to break.

Comment: @MarkKaplun first, please believe me, what I want is not tables; this is definitely for layout and not for data. Each content block will contain many paragraphs, images, videos and possibly even tables. Second, they are rules for a reason, just because something can be made to work, doesn't mean it should be. One of the big reasons for not using tables for layout aids is accessibility. Consider the sight-impaired, read up on web accessibility. People like you, who ignore web standards, are ruining the web. To paraphrase you 'people who ignore web standards should not be in web design'.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like a perfect use of [Advanced Custom Fields "flexible content"](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) feature to me. Flexible content fields allow you to define multiple layouts, and then add them to a page or post one by one, in any order or combination you need. Each layout can be a combination of text fields, images, wysiwyg editors, and other field types.

It's a brilliant UI on the client side, and easy to build a custom front-end in your template once you get the hang of it.

It's a premium plugin, but I've been building these kinds of interfaces for many years and it works really well. I haven't found anything else quite like it.

Comment: thanks for the info. I looked into Advanced Custom Fields but wasn't getting the results I wanted. I did not look into the premium features however. I will definitely investigate this further. Plus 1 for trying to help me get the solution I want rather than offering a potential alternative solution. (Not that the alternative solutions are unwanted).

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to code the Visual Editor so your content editors can highlight parts of the post content, rather than trying to add a large number of extra content blocks to the edit screen.

Here's what I use, the basics of which I think I got from the Codex originally, a long time ago.

```
// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function wpse241267_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}

add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'wpse241267_mce_buttons_2');
```

This just enables the Style dropdown menu at the left hand end of the second row of Visual Editor buttons.

Now for the meat:

```
function wpse241267_mce_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  

    $style_formats = array(  
        // Each array child is a format with its own settings

        array(  
            'title' => 'Find Us Block',  
            'block' => 'div',  
            'classes' => 'find-us',
            'wrapper' => true,
            'exact' => true,

        ),
    );  

    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'

    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

    return $init_array;  

} 

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse241267_mce_insert_formats' );
```

You can use IDs instead of classes if you want, but I don't think there's anything to prevent a user adding more than one into a page.

Then in the Visual Editor you can highlight some content, apply this style from the dropdown and the highlighted content will be surrounded by a `div` with the class `find-us`.

The `exact` argument prevents the editor merging multiple adjacent blocks.  Depending on your case you may wish to remove this.

Comment: Andy, thanks so much for coming back and providing this, I really appreciate it. It's the end of my day now, but I will get into this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion. It works. But it's not perfect. I feel it is only a little bit more user friendly than the shortcodes. I am going to continue investigating a UI solution.

Comment: No problem. Yeh, it was meant more as an easy to implement improvement.

Comment: @JDD Have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49906/94267 which explains how to add a metabox with the visual editor.  I was putting together another answer when I saw this one already there.